# Using Bootstrap grid structure(col-sm) in form controls for defining width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, coding-style

Can I use `col-sm` or `col-xs` in my input tag for defining its width?

```
<div>
<input type="button" class="col-sm-2" value="Reset">
<input type="button" class="col-sm-2" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use bootstrap grid classes on any element that has those attributes to change.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use multiple classes dependence on your requirement.

```
<div>
<input type="button" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" value="Reset">
</div>
```

[you can also refer this site](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)